# InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments

This is the scenario, I copied the classes from my old project to my new one. then when I run it, the class that inflates my datetimepicker is looking for my old project

here is my logcat

> 12-11 02:09:25.162
>   5864-5864/com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.erlawkward.albarol.eventlocatorapp.activity.activity.AccessibleTextView
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator.Time.TimePickerDialog.onCreateView(TimePickerDialog.java:366)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.erlawkward.albarol.eventlocatorapp.activity.activity.AccessibleTextView"
>   on path: /data/app/com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator-2.apk
>                                                                                                  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
>                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.erlawkward.albarol.capstoneeventlocator.Time.TimePickerDialog.onCreateView(TimePickerDialog.java:366) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
>                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

as you can see in this line of my logcat that my copied class is still looking for my old project. I already tried deleting the class and made a new one but still it is looking my old project. sorry for my bad english, i explained it with everything i can.

> "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.erlawkward.albarol.eventlocatorapp.activity.activity.AccessibleTextView"

Comment: Somewhere in your xml-layout is still using your AccessibleTextView class from your old project. Try to search for that tag and replace it with your new class

Comment: yea you ar eright, i searched the actuvuty and changed it. it works fine now. thanks :)